# How to display more than one column data from the same table on ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

My ListView currently is able to display only one column data. I want it to display two column data.

Here is the code for my ListView:

```
public class ProjectExplorer extends ListActivity {

private projectdatabase database;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    database = new projectdatabase(ProjectExplorer.this);

    getinfo();
}

private void getinfo() {

    database.open();
    cursor = database.getDataforDisplay();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[] {"project_name"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);

    Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getCursor();
      c.moveToPosition(position);

      // get project name here

      String str_projectname= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("project_name"));

      Toast.makeText(this, str_projectname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Here is the method in database class which return the cursor:

```
public Cursor getDataforDisplay () {    

    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_FINISH_DATE, PROJECT_DIFFICULTY, PROJECT_STATUS};
    Cursor c = projectDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    projectDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

}
```

I also want to display KEY_ROWID which is defined as _id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 specifying column no.2 from table from where data can be retrieved and specifies location with help of it can be displayed on Activity - android.R.id.text2

```
  adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, new String[] {"project_name","column_no2"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1, andriod.R.id.text2 }, 0);
```

You can also create your on custom Adapter specifying your own Listview and creating it from scratch and customized everything.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this at least in my opinion is to create custom Adapter for your `ListView` in that case you can set your own design how single listview element should look like . Just populate some arrays using your `Cursor` and set them to your custom adapter.